# Source for whole genome comparisons at NCBI Genomes

Tags: phylogenetics, genbank

The NCBI Genomes database has these dendrograms for (presumably) whole genome comparisons for certain species, e.g. [Pseudonomas aeruginosa](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/?term=txid208964[Organism:exp])  or [Escherichia coli](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genome/167).

How were these comparisons done? Someone knows the source / paper?

Comment: They say "based on genomic BLAST". No useful information can be found, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I inquired into the details of the dendrograms after becoming frustrated with the lack of information. As with Ensembl, I'm sure that the folks at NCBI have a standardized pipeline that they run the sequences through to generate these dendrograms as no specific source deserving attribution was mentioned:

> The tree is based on a pairwise, BLAST comparison of chromosome sequences (an assembly is used for genomes with 2 or more chromosomes). BLAST identity is normalized on sequence length. The distance map is generated by a Neighbor Joining algorithm, where the distance is the blast score.
>
> *Dr. Wayne Matten, NCBI*

Comment: Thanks for inquiring. Too bad that their response doesn't contain more details or a link to the pipeline. Seems like they calculate the average PID of all alignments reported by blastn und use that as a distance measure. I wonder if they also consider the parts of each genome pair that are not covered by alignments.